# How to manage xml templates? Need some examples

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I am building a small scale python app which will maintain multiple xml templates for EMAILS. It will build the xml and send request to the mail server.

Example template:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EMAIL_TYPE1>
   <EMAIL_ADDRESS>${email_address}</EMAIL_ADDRESS>
   <SUBJECT>${subject}</SUBJECT>
   <CONFIRMED_ORDERS>
      <ORDER>
         <ID>${item_id}</ID>
         <NAME>${item_name}</NAME>
         <PRICE>${item_price}</PRICE>
      </ORDER>
      <ORDER>
         <ID>${item_id}</ID>
         <NAME>${item_name}</NAME>
         <PRICE>${item_price}</PRICE>
      </ORDER>
   </CONFIRMED_ORDERS>
   <PENDING_ORDERS>
      <ORDER>
         <ID>${item_id}</ID>
         <NAME>${item_name}</NAME>
         <PRICE>${item_price}</PRICE>
      </ORDER>
   </PENDING_ORDERS>
   <CANCELLED_ORDER>
      <ORDER>
         <ID>${item_id}</ID>
         <NAME>${item_name}</NAME>
         <PRICE>${item_price}</PRICE>
      </ORDER>
   </CANCELLED_ORDER>
</EMAIL_TYPE1>
```

I am going to have different templates for different emails.

My use-case is like upon receiving a certain mail request, I will fetch data from DATABASE and fill up these templates by replacing the placeholders with actual data.

I have seen some examples that use String replacement, but how to handle List of data like I have `CONFIRMED_ORDERS`?

What is the best way to achieve this in Python? I am also trying to achieve a Configuration based approach so that in future when new templates are added no code change is required.

Comment: That's not how the things goes here. You have to show us your attempts, then if you failed after searching/testing/experimenting, then you can ask

Answer (score 0):

I was able to meet this requirement.
I have added the code in Github Here's the Link

https://github.com/ishankghosh/xmlTemplateParsing

Feel free to comment.

Thanks